# C# Is there a way to use a variable AS a property?

Tags: c#, string, variables, properties

I want to use a variable, here i'm using TextName as the variable.
then use it AS a property. Of course i cannot because it's a string, but how do i get a variable/string to be treated as the text in the string it's holding? In google sheets this is very similuar to something called an INDIRECT, to be able to be the data you are referring to.

```
// Code I like to write:
TextName = "richTextBox";
TextName.Text = "text for richTextBox";
```

I want that code to be treated as

```
richTextBox.Text = "text for richTextBox";
```

but with `richTextBox.Text` in full or part to be a variable, so that I can put this entire thing in a method, and only change the variable, and not have an entire method all over the code over and over.

I'm using .NET6.0 if it matters.

Comment: You need to use something like `FindControl(TextName)` or `Controls.Where(c => c.Name == TextName)`. But often the need for this is the result of a serious design mistake made earlier, and you're better off going back to the drawing board on why you're in this position in the first place.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Can i get a full example? (I tried and got FindControl does not exist in current context) adding a space gives a ton of errors, and Controls. Where says no definition for Where.

Also... im not sure how that could be a serious design mistake, surely searching for something via variable is way more efficent when writing an entire method over and over and having hundreds-thousands of lines of code, for something that only needs one property.

EDIT; Upon closer inspection, i think it's just FindControl isn't being accepted, does it work on .NET6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are going to do this in a Form. In this case, you can add this code into your form:

```
public string this[string name]
{
    get
    {
        return this.Controls.ContainsKey(name) ?
            this.Controls[name].Text :
            null;
    }
        
    set
    {
        if (this.Controls.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            var control = this.Controls[name];
            control.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And get/set the text of any `Control` in this way:

```
this["richTextBox"] = "text for richTextBox";

var text = this["richTextBox"];
```

`this` is your form.

If you are going to use in multiple forms, you can create an extension methods:

```
public static class FormExtends
{
    public static string GetText(this Form form, string name, string defaultText = null)
    {
        return form.Controls.ContainsKey(name) ?
            form.Controls[name].Text :
            (defaultText ?? string.Empty);
    }

    public static void SetText(this Form form, string name, string text)
    {
        if (form.Controls.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            var control = form.Controls[name];
            control.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

And simplify the code in each form:

```
public string this[string name]
{
    get { return this.GetText(name); }
    set { this.SetText(name, value); }
}
```

Comment: alright, i've gone back and forth on replying or fiddling more as this sounds stupid, but something simple must be going over my head, i used those, and still tried TextName or text in place of the property the array is writing to but...uh, nothing, it just gives me Text for richTextBox INSIDE the textbox, instead of the number 5 being pulled from the array.. How am i suppose to actually *use* this?

Comment: wait, i maybe got it working (i would of edited but it said i can't edit longer then 5 minutes >_>;)

Comment: For onlookers later, i don't use
this["richTextBox"] = "text for richTextBox";
var text = this["richTextBox"];
instead i use this[TextName]  (or other variable that is a string) in place of the controls name, and it works. Still have to have the other part of code he posted be somewhere.

Thanks Victor!

Comment: form.Controls["xxx"] give you the Control instance that have it's Name="xxx". You can use a string directly or a variable of type string, it's the same. Any Control derived class (TextBox, RichTextBox...) has the Text property, which is the property that extension methods are getting/setting.